# Extjs4 Load data in grid from server

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc, extjs-grid

How to load data in grid from server I am able to load data from Store to grid but not able to load data from server to the store and then into grid Server API Details :

http://192.1681.102:8080/Petcrumbs/member/getMemberList

Request Parameters :

{"pageNumber":5}

### Response Success :

{
   "listOfMembers":
   [
       {
           "address":
           {
               "state": "MH",
               "country": "India",
               "city": "Pune",
               "addressId": 52,
               "streetName": "Karve Road",
               "streetNameTwo": "Nal Stop",
               "zipCode": "412042"
           },
           "name": "Test Mmber4",
           "password": "287974",
           "authKey": "99710ff8d98346f51a7b3df83c16257",
           "gender": "Male",
           "deviceToken": "ldjhakjhdkjahn42,n4lk2jedlkandmandlkand",
           "community": "Kothrud",
           "emailId": "r.pekam@mb.com",
           "phone": "9096305571",
           "image": null,
           "memberId": 41,
           "active": 1,
           "deleted": false,
           "myPackage": "Gold",
           "joinedDate": "09-17-2013"
       }
 ],
   "message": "Member retrieved successfully.",
   "success": true
}

### Response Failure :

{
  "listOfMembers": null,
  "message": "Unable to retrieve members.",
  "success": false

}

---

In EXTJS Store

```
 Ext.define('PetCrumbs.store.Members', {
extend : 'Ext.data.ArrayStore',
model : 'PetCrumbs.model.Member',

autoLoad : true,
//storeId : 'Data',
proxy : {
    type : 'ajax',
    url : '/Petcrumbs/member/getMemberList',
    method : 'POST',
    headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'Accept' : 'application/json'
    },
    jsonData : {
        pageNumber : "5"
    },
    reader : {
        type : 'json',
        root: 'listOfMembers',
        successProperty: 'success'
    }
 }
});
```

When I have Store like this ( Hard Coded Data ) grid displays data :

```
Ext.define('PetCrumbs.store.Members', {
extend: 'Ext.data.ArrayStore',
model: 'PetCrumbs.model.Member',

data: [
['1','1002','Asin','kothroud@gmail.com','kothrud,Pune','MH',
 'Pune','411051','Male','Gold','Kothrud','1'],['2','1012','Karina','Pashan@gmail.com',
'Pashan,Pune','MH','Pune','411051','Female','Silver','Pashan','0']
]   
});
```

Please tell me what is wrong with the above code ?

Comment: As others said, you should use JsonStore. But you should also check your Model definition...sometimes when using Array data (as in first example), you use a "mapping" config to define the field, but with the Json response you have, that will be no longer needed. Post your Model definition if you'd like more help.

Comment: Existdissolve,model: var types=Ext.data.Types;
Ext.define('PetCrumbs.model.Member', { extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
fields : [{name : 'srNo',type : types.INT}, {name : 'memberId',
type : types.INT}, {name : 'memberName',type : types.STRING}, {
name : 'emailId',type : types.STRING}, {name : 'address',type : types.STRING}, {name : 'state',type : types.STRING}, {name : 'city',
type : types.STRING}, {name : 'zip',type : types.STRING}, {name : 'gender',type : types.STRING}, {name : 'myPackage',type :types.STRING}, {name : 'joinedCommunities',type : types.STRING
}, {name : 'deleted',type : types.BOOL},

Comment: {name : 'password',type : types.STRING}, {name : 'phone',type : types.STRING}, {name : 'street',type : types.STRING}]});   I have used store bt the result is same ......

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify the way your server sends the data? the easiest would be to use a plain `Ext.data.Store` with `Ext.data.reader.Json`. To use this your JSON should look like:

```
{ 
   "listOfMembers": [
   {"attr1":"value1",:"attr2":"value2",...},... 
   ], 
   "message": "Unable to retrieve members.", "success": false
}
```

Then it will be straight forward.

If you want to continue with your output you have to either modify the reader or define more complex object relations.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you use `ArrayStore`, which works well with locally hardcoded data (as it is array), but when you want to load data remotely - you should extend `Ext.data.Store` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You are using ArrayStore, but server returns JSON. So you should use JsonStore. Or just basic store with configured reader

Comment: @Ram and can you provide or just review your model defenition?

Comment: @Ram at first - try to change adress type - it isn`t string, its object. Also look at http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-hasMany and http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-belongsTo